# How to solve this system of equations analytically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$ \begin{cases} \ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2-r\left[\sin\left(\theta\right)\right]^2\dot{\varphi}^2 &=&0 \\\ddot{\theta}+\frac{2}{r}\dot{\theta}\dot{r}-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\theta\right)\dot{\varphi}^2 &= &0 \\ \ddot{\varphi}+\frac{2}{r}\dot{\varphi}\dot{r}+2\cot\left(\theta\right)\dot{\varphi}\dot{\theta} &= &0\end{cases}$$
Where the dot is derivative by some parameter $t$. No particular initial conditions are given, so I guess I'd want to see a general solution given generic initial conditions $r(0)=r_0;\theta(0)=\theta_0;\varphi(0)=\varphi_0$ and likewise for the first derivatives.

Comment: What do you mean likewise for the first derivatives? Why do you think it has an analytic solution?

Comment: What I mean is that the first derivatives are also given as constants: $\dot{r}(0)=v_0;\dot{\theta}(0)=u_0;\dot{\varphi}(0)=w_0$. I don't _know_ that it does but I was hoping for it.